# How to stop HTML form from returning undefined value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to retrieve the input value of an HTML form, but the variable only returns undefined when outside of a function.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form name="form">
        Enter name: 
   <input type="text" id="answer">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="answerInput()">
</form>
```

And here is the JS that goes with it:

```
function answerInput() {
    username = document.getElementById("answer").value
}
console.log(username)
```

When the `console.log(username)` statement is within the function, it returns the input; however, when the `console.log(username)` statement is outside the function, it returns undefined.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If console.log(username) is outside the function, its going to get called before you ever press the button, so it makes sense it would be undefined there.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the username?  You should likely handle that inside the answerInput() function (if it doesn't belong in there, you can make a new function that answerInput() calls)

Comment: @Travis I made a new function to handle username that is called by answerInput() and it worked, thanks for helping me realize what was wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call console.log inside your function.

```js
function answerInput() {
    username = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    console.log(username)
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
        Enter name: 
   <input type="text" id="answer">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="answerInput()">
</form>
```